# Why do my "hidden" managed metadata columns have GUIDs as internal names?

Tags: managed-metadata

When I create my managed meta data column called MyField in my develop environment it gets a "hidden field" with the suffix "_0" (MyField_0). This field has an internal and a static name with the fields name and an ending with "TaxHTField0" (MyFieldTaxHTField0). And so everything is working as supposed in the develop environment.
Then the problem arrives in the production environment where I in some code using content types using the column get the exception that no field with the internal name "MyFieldTaxHTField0" could be found and might be deleted by some other user. And when I look at the field with SharePoint Manager 2010 I see that it has a GUID as an internal and static name!

Ive tried creating managed field both with the GUI and the Object model. With the same results. I can change the static name of the field, but not the internal, which seems to be the one used by SharePoints internals.

Anyone having a clue what could be creating this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, creating Managed Metadata columns, packaging them (in WSP) and move them from one environment to another is not as straightforward as one would think. If you would like to learn internals of these columns, please go on reading following series of articles from Andrew:

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2011/06/15/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-about-the-series.aspx

In [last article](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2011/07/25/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-creating-managed-metadata-columns.aspx) of the series, he discuss how to create Managed Metadata columns programmatically.